# Changing Coarse Iron to Iron?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, mods

Note I am using the Masterwork Mod, looked through the manual didn't see anything about coarse iron. How do I change coarse Iron to normal Iron with the Masterwork Mod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coarse Iron has the following uses in Masterwork 1.9.5:

- In a crucible, use "cold hammer coarse iron" to turn the ore into coarse iron bars
- In the same crucible (with additional fuel) or a magma crucible, use "refine coarse iron into iron" to turn coarse iron bars into iron bars.

It, along with the both crucibles, is being removed in Masterwork 2.

Comment: good the idea of coarse metal seems pointless and just extra work.